# How to move an image on the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have this simple shooting canvas game which runs just fine. But my issue is that I want the image to do the shooting and not the blue rectangle? So how I can make my image move and shoot the orange rectangles that come down?

Here's my code:

```
function initCanvas(){
var ctx = document.getElementById('my_canvas').getContext('2d');
var img = document.getElementById("nave");
var myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = "pic.gif";
ctx.drawImage(myImage,10,10);
var cW = ctx.canvas.width, cH = ctx.canvas.height;
```

Comment: Looks like you need to try some simple-game-tutorial-in-html5?

Comment: no, how can I do that?

Comment: this explains it a little more: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp its accurate enough for the basic idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like you already have the image:

```
var myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = "pic.gif";
```

Now you just need to redraw the image at the new position in the render function... so instead of using fixed position of 20,20, use the position based on variables:

```
ctx.drawImage(myImage, this.x, this.y);
```

Comment: @programador-xpert No problem! :)